# ReactiveSwift: How to subscribe to SignalProducer?

Tags: swift, reactive-swift, reactive-cocoa-5

I'm trying to learn ReactiveSwift and ReactiveCocoa. I can use `Signal` and `Property` pretty well, but I'm having trouble with `SignalProducer`.

As I understand it, `SignalProducer` is ideal for things like network requests. I set up my API layer to create and return a signal provider, which the caller can start.

```
class ApiLayer {
    func prepareRequest(withInfo info: RequestInfo) -> SignalProducer<ModelType, ErrorType> {
        return SignalProducer<ModelType, ErrorType> { (observer, lifetime) in

            // Send API Request ...

            // In Completion Handler:
            let result = parseJson(json)
            observer.send(value: result)
            observer.sendCompleted()
        }
    }
}
```

**But how am I supposed to listen for the results?**

I've tried something like this, but I get an error, so I must be doing / thinking about this wrong.

```
apiLayer.prepareRequest(withInfo: info)
    .startWithValues { (resultModel) in
        // Do Stuff with result ...
}
```

Here's the error I get:

> ### Ambiguous reference to member 'startWithValues'
>
> 1. Found this candidate (ReactiveSwift.SignalProducer< Value, NoError >)
> 2. Found this candidate (ReactiveSwift.SignalProducer< Never, NoError >)

**EDIT**

I tried being more explicit to help the compiler identify the proper method, like so. But the error still remains.

```
apiLayer.prepareRequest(withInfo: info)
    .startWithValues { (resultModel: ModelType) in // Tried adding type. Error remained.
        // Do Stuff with result ...
}
```

**EDIT 2**

After getting help over at the GitHub support page and thinking about the provided answer here, here's what I ended up with.

One key difference from my earlier attempts is that the caller doesn't manually start the returned `SignalProducer`. Rather, by creating it inside/in response to another signal, it's implicitly started inside the chain.

I had previously (incorrectly) assumed that it was necessary to extract and explicitly subscribe to the `Signal` that a `SignalProducer` "produced".

Instead, I now think about `SignalProducer`s simply as deferred work that is kickstarted in response to stimuli. I can manually subscribe to the `SignalProvider` or I can let another `Signal` provide that stimulus instead. (The latter used in my updated sample below. It seems fairly clean and much more FRP-esque than manually starting it, which I had carried over from my imperative mindset.)

```
enum ErrorType: Error {
    case network
    case parse
}
class ApiLayer {
    func prepareRequest(withInfo info: RequestInfo) -> SignalProducer<ModelType, ErrorType> {
        let producer = SignalProducer<ResultType, NoError> { (observer, lifetime) in

            sendRequest(withInfo: info) { result in
                observer.send(value: result)
                observer.sendCompleted()
            }

        }

        return producer
            .attemptMap { result throws -> ResultType in
                let networkError: Bool = checkResult(result)
                if (networkError) {
                    throw ErrorType.network
                }
            }
            .retry(upTo: 2)
            .attemptMap { result throws -> ModelType in
                // Convert result
                guard let model: ModelType = convertResult(result) else {
                    throw ErrorType.parse
                }
                return model
            }
            // Swift infers AnyError as some kind of error wrapper.
            // I don't fully understand this part yet, but to match the method's type signature, I needed to map it.
            .mapError { $0.error as! ErrorType}
    }
}

// In other class/method
// let apiLayer = ApiLayer(with: ...)
// let infoSignal: Signal<RequestInfo, NoError> = ...
infoSignal
    .flatMap(.latest) { (info) in
        apiLayer.prepareRequest(withInfo: info)
    }
    .flatMapError { error -> SignalProducer<ModelType, NoError> in
        // Handle error
        // As suggested by the ReactiveSwift documentation,
        // return empty SignalProducer to map/remove the error type
        return SignalProducer<ModelType, NoError>.empty
    }
    .observeValues { model in
        // Do stuff with result ...
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ReactiveSwift`'s philosophy is that it shouldn't be easy for users to ignore errors. So `startWithValues` is only available if the producer's error type is `NoError`, which ensures that no error can ever be sent. If your producer *can* send an error, you need to use a function like `startWithResult` which will allow you to handle it:

```
apiLayer.prepareRequest(withInfo: info).startWithResult { result in
    switch result {
    case let .success(model):
        // Do stuff with model
    case let .failure(error):
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: I also asked this on the GitHub support page [here](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/issues/574):

andersio correctly pointed out that `startWithResult` is unavailable because of the error type. And now I see that `extension ... where` clause in the source. But thank you for pointing out the philosophy of explicitly handling and transforming errors.

I was trying to work on success cases before going back and handling the error cases, so I didn't know **why** it was set up that way.

Comment: Also, I just didn't actually understand how to use signal providers. Thanks to your and andersio's comments, I'm starting to understand the correct way to think about `Signal`s, `SignalProvider`s, and FRP in general.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring errors isn't a good idea but in some cases, it's possible to treat them as nil values with such an extension:

```
public extension SignalProducer {
    func skipErrors() -> SignalProducer<Value?, NoError> {
        return self
            .flatMap(.latest, { SignalProducer<Value?, NoError>(value: $0) })
            .flatMapError { _ in SignalProducer<Value?, NoError>(value: nil) }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a bad idea. This type of extension could be useful.